# Find real number $x$ such that $\sqrt[4]{2+x}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}=\sqrt[6]{4-x^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

$\sqrt[4]{2+x}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}=\sqrt[6]{4-x^2}$ find real number $x$. I have tried powering, some substitutions but I couldn't go anywhere. Please help.

Comment: i think a numercal method will help you

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Comment: ... and why do you think there is a reasonable algebraic solution? Do you really *need* an algebraic solution? Why?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $\sqrt[3]{2+x}$ instead of $\sqrt[4]{2+x}$ there?

Comment: @MartinSleziak. I suppose that you are totally correct (for sure). May be, one more typo in a textbook. Otherwise, it would be a monster to solve. Cheers.

Comment: It is given by (some) of the solutions of $4096x^{24}+22036608 x^{23}+29595985665 x^{22}-119674156008 x^{21}-914493921270
   x^{20}+4128254550300 x^{19}+12225200309657 x^{18}-63988538668524 x^{17}-94114183551132
   x^{16}+599484836230784 x^{15}+456183613955904 x^{14}-3847410978888960
   x^{13}-1225373509190400 x^{12}+17812960085397504 x^{11}-696818001166848
   x^{10}-58884797478307840 x^9+21985821606819840 x^8+129331767321526272
   x^7-90451821162446848 x^6-160351059677872128 x^5+170018725664587776
   x^4+64343774980210688 x^3-124652305370775552 x^2+38761963430608896 x-4558227022544896$.

Comment: Oy!  Maybe the first term is a cube root?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: note that $$4-x^2=(2-x)(2+x)$$
p.s.: set $$2-x=a,2+x=b$$ and you will have

$$b^{1/4}=a^{1/6}b^{1/6}+a^{1/3}$$ and $$a+b=4$$